# Is it possible to display an arbritrary string in the web browser class without saving it?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

It looks like you can send it to an url, but how to you get it to display an arbritrary html stored as a string without saving to a file first?

Basically I want have a string which has a parcel of html code:

```
string webpage = @"<html><body><h1>Hello World </h1></body></html>";
```

I then want to display it in the web browser control.

Comment: Your question is unclear - what do you mean by "saving it"? Are you *actually* talking about navigating to an arbitrary URL, or are you talking about displaying HTML? Please put some time into clarifying your question.

Comment: Define _arbritrary_ (and i don't mean the typo).

Comment: Are you looking for  `DocumentText` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign any string to [`DocumentText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) property of the webbrowser control...